# How to set device permissions using udev programmatically

Tags: c++, c, linux, udev

In short:

I have written some code in which I detect new device connections using udev. What I want is prevent detected device from being used.

There is some way to do that programmatically? There is some udev api for setting udev_device permissions?

Comment: You should have set up udev rules. Before now. These do what you just asked automatically with new devices. Do not use chmod().  It is not straightforward.  Here's a link: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gizmod/index.php?title=HOWTO_-_Setting_Input_Device_Permissions_-_Creating_a_udev_Rule

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't want use udev rules. PD: The link you provide me is broken.

Comment: It is not broken for me but here it is in text form:        'sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gizmod/index.php?title=HOWTO_-_Setting_Input_Device_Permissions_-_Creating_a_udev_Rule'

Comment: Sorry, All I got was:

**There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, search the related logs, or edit this page.**

Thanks any way.